# jQuery - Can't add a class to a button with an onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to add a class to a button that has an `onClick` event. The `onClick` event triggers a popup `alert` that tells the user to check a box. Once you check a box, it disables the `onClick`: `$("#continue").prop('onclick',null).off('click');` Once the `onClick` is disabled, I want to add a `class` to the button once it is clicked:

```
//Updated JS
jQuery(function($) {
 if ($("#continue").hasClass("selected")) {
  $(this).addClass('active');
 }
 $('#button').click(function(){
  $("#continue").addClass('selected');
  $("#continue").prop('onclick',null).off('click');
 });
});

//Button HTML
<a id="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Pick me</a>
<a id="continue" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showError()">Continue</a>
```

But no `class` gets added. Not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can trigger a function to validate if the element has the required class like this:

```js
function validate(element) {
  if ($(element).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(element).addClass('active');
  } else  {
    alert("this is an error");
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $("#continue").addClass('selected');
  });

});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="button" href="javascript:;">Pick me</a>
<a id="continue" href="javascript:;" onclick="validate(this)">Continue</a>
```

Comment: please insert a snippet with all your code.  Be aware that alerts, props, etc stops the execution of javascripts until the user has dismissed the alert.

Comment: Here is my code http://pastebin.com/s5mKxTaA It's not a normal alert, its a custom one

Comment: This is what I see in my console: $ is not a function http://pastebin.com/pikNXrG1

Comment: You need to load jquery. Before using any jquery syntax.

Comment: Ok, I did that. Now it's showing this: validate is not defined https://gyazo.com/549b1584a899ccadc066511bc5055e39 Thank you for your help so far

Comment: Make sure validate function is defined right after you load jquery. You can't call a fubction in a script if it hasn't been defined before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112554/discussion-between-garrettj944-and-alfredo).

Answer (score 1):

You should write `$(this)` instead of $this

```
$('#button').click(function(){
     $this.addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Wrapping `this` in parenthesis made it work.  `$(this).addClass('active')`